# Limit takes too long

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I want to compute the following limit

```
Limit[
  Integrate[BetaRegularized[(2 h - h^2), (d - 1)/2, 1/2], {h, 0, 1}], 
  d -> Infinity
]
```

However, surprisingly, it takes too long. Is there any technique to simplify this task in such a way that Mathematica can accomplish it in a reasonable amount of time?

Comment: 1) Why is it surprising that it takes a long time? Is this a known result? 2) Have you noticed that the integral itself returns unevaluated?

Comment: @MarcoB I am to new to Mathematica, I was thinking it is simple. It is easy to analytically show that the function argument of the limit is asymptotic to $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi d}}$ for $d\to\infty$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can change the variable `2h-h^2->z`  by hand.

```
Reduce[z == 2 h - h^2 && 1 > h > 0, h, Reals]
```

> `0 < z < 1 && h == 1 - Sqrt[1 - z]`

```
1/D[2 h - h^2, h] /. h -> 1 - Sqrt[1 - z] // Simplify
```

> `1/(2 Sqrt[1 - z])`

It means that the change variable is one to one and $0<z<1$, $\mathrm{d}h=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{1-z}}$

```
Integrate[
 BetaRegularized[z, (d - 1)/2, 1/2]*1/(2 Sqrt[1 - z]), {z, 0, 1}]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[2/((-1 + d) Beta[1/2 (-1 + d), 1/2]),  Re[d] > -1]`

```
Limit[%, d -> ∞]
```

> `0`

So the result is $0$.

We can verify this result by `NIntegrate`.

```
With[{d = 100000000000}, 
 NIntegrate[BetaRegularized[(2 h - h^2), (d - 1)/2, 1/2], {h, 0, 1}, 
  AccuracyGoal -> 30, PrecisionGoal -> 50]]
```

> `0`.

```
DiscretePlot[
 NIntegrate[
  BetaRegularized[(2 h - h^2), (d - 1)/2, 1/2], {h, 0, 1}], {d, 10, 
  100}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Joined -> False, Filling -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: Not really sure that the first `NIntegrate` is showing what is claimed. You should set `WorkingPrecision` much higher than `PrecisionGoal`, say `100` (and why reduce the `AccuracyGoal`?).

Comment: @MichaelE2  There are no other meaning there,just avoid the warning message :)  I do not understand the settings of precision.

Comment: With `WorkingPrecision -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 30`, the value of the integral I got on WolframCloud was ~10^-6, which seemed a more reasonable result.  With machine precision the integrand is not computed correctly (there are errors, which are probably caught by `NIntegrate` which probably increases the internal working precision automatically). But this morning on my laptop, I don't need `MaxRecursion` and the result is ~10^-998, which is even stronger evidence. I can't explain the difference with WC. The result `0.`, when it's unlikely to be exactly zero, tends to make me suspicious.